# Combobox and timer in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

The code after edit is:

```
private void Form1_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

    {
        try
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text == "Present")
            {

                label47.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                label9.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(); 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Oh come on!  What have you tried?  This is not a homework service!

Comment: There's no question here, just code with no explanation. What's the specific problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

use selected index changed event

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,System.EventArgs e)
{
 try
 {
   if(ComboBox1.Text == "present")
    {
      label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm");
    } 
 }catch(Exception)
 {
 }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any error, but it doesn't work!!

Comment: the date and time didn't appear on the label when I selected present!!, I don't know why.

Comment: try DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();for the time and DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(); for the date

use it like that if you want :
label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() +" "+DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() ;

Comment: Also, it doesn't work! ,I will cry. Should I have to use code in cs for label ? or not?.In addition to the code that you gave me.

Comment: please post your whole code what are you trying to do

Comment: it doesn't accept to put the whole code, it said that is too long. What should I do?

Comment: take a look. I didn't write the codes for all the buttons yet, I mean that I didn't complete my system because I have many questions regarding it.

Comment: that { first line of the event and } at the end of the event is it a copy paste mistake or you're executing the code like that ?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what I have to remove?

Comment: I removed the first" { " and the last "}" but it didn't work ! I will edit the question, take a look.

Comment: does it give you an error exception ??
try MessageBox.Show("Error"); inside the catch block

Comment: it doesn't give me any error but it doesn't work , that is weird!

Comment: i'm sorry i need the whole project to help you seeking for the problem :/

Comment: how to send you the whole project ?! , can you give me your email? or what